# when I try to zip apiece of html to separated page and zip it not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I try to download a piece of HTML to a separated page and zip it using java script, it is not working

```
var zip = new JSZip();

var html = $("#editor")[0].innerHTML;

zip.file("extraction.html", html);

jQuery("#cmd").on("click",
function() {
    debugger;
    zip.generateAsync({
        type: "base64"
    }).then(function(base64) {
        window.location = "data:application/zip;base64," + base64;
    },
    function(err) {
        debugger;
        jQuery("#data_uri").text(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I replace 
`zip.file("extraction.html", html);`
with 
`zip.file("extraction.html", html, "text/html");`
the problem is solved